# Descriptive column instead Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *
    , AreaLeftOver=(KmSquared) % (20761)
    , WhalesUnit = (KmSquared)/(20761)
    , WhalesComparison= case when((KmSquared)/(20761) * (KmSquared) % (20761)  )>0 then (KmSquared)/(20761) * (KmSquared) % (20761) else  'Smaller' end
from CountriesByArea 
order by Country
```

How can I achieve a descriptive column for `WhalesComparison`?

I tried using case when statement but it gives me int values which throws me conversion error from 'varchar to bigint'.

Note: I only have Country, KmSquared columns rest I have derived from calculating functions.

Comment: Can you provide some example data, a basic schema and the output you desire?

Comment: output: '31 x whales plus 3909 sq.km'  for WhalesComparison 
I dont need the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT POSITION
,COUNTRY
,KmSquared
,AreaLeftOver
,WhalesUnit
,CASE WHEN CALC <= 0 THEN 'SMALLER'
WHEN CALC > 0 THEN AreaLeftOver+''+ 'x WALES PLUS'+ '' + WhalesUnit
ELSE 'NONE'
END AS [Wales Comparision]
FROM
(
select POSITION
,COUNTRY
,KmSquared
,CAST(KmSquared % 20761 AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS AreaLeftOver
,CAST(KmSquared / 20761 AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS WhalesUnit
,((KmSquared % 20761) * (KmSquared / 20761)) AS CALC
from CountriesByArea 
)A
order by Country
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix datatypes in a single column. You have a formula that returns an int or a string. You can't do this but you can return everything as a string. You also don't need parenthesis around every column in a calculation.

```
select *
    , AreaLeftOver= KmSquared % 20761
    , WhalesUnit = KmSquared / 20761
    , WhalesComparsion= case when KmSquared / 20761 * KmSquared % 20761 > 0 then convert(varchar(10), KmSquared / 20761 * KmSquared % 20761) else  'Smaller' end
from CountriesByArea 
order by Country
```

Or even better would be to include the text 'Smaller' in your application and simply return NULL.

```
select *
    , AreaLeftOver= KmSquared % 20761
    , WhalesUnit = KmSquared / 20761
    , WhalesComparsion= case when KmSquared / 20761 * KmSquared % 20761 > 0 then KmSquared / 20761 * KmSquared % 20761) end
from CountriesByArea 
order by Country
```